# How to load images and labels to image_data_layer using Python?

Tags: python, neural-network, caffe

I'm trying to load images to a network and calculate the top 5 error rate. My data layer is

```
name: "CaffeNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  image_data_param {
      source: "/home/filipa/PycharmProjects/Proposal_Code/Labels/val.txt"

  }
}
```

where val.txt file have the name of each image and correspondent label. (Total 50000 images)

My last layers are

```
 name: "fc8"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1000
  }
}
layer {
  name: "prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "fc8"
  top: "prob"
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy_top_5"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy_top_5"
  accuracy_param {
    top_k: 5
  }
 include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
E1116 11:34:28.173830  7465 io.cpp:80] Could not open or find file ILSVRC2012_val_00000001.JPEG
F1116 11:34:28.173835  7465 image_data_layer.cpp:72] Check failed: cv_img.data Could not load ILSVRC2012_val_00000001.JPEG
```

In my code, I load the image to the network as

```
im = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_FILE)
```

where IMAGE_FILE points to the exact location of my images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would edit the prototxt to be:

```
  image_data_param {
      root_folder: "/home/filipa/PycharmProjects/root/folder/for/data"
      source: "/home/filipa/PycharmProjects/Proposal_Code/Labels/val.txt"
  }
```

And then set the paths in "val.txt" to be relative to the `root_folder`.